# how to get messages by date using TELETHON?

Tags: python, telethon

how to get message that posted today using `TELETHON`

I'm using the below code

```
date_of_post = datetime.datetime(2019, 12, 24)

with TelegramClient(name, api_id, api_hash) as client:
    for message in client.iter_messages(chat , offset_date = date_of_post):
        print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`offset_date` is used to get messages *prior* to that date. So you should use the day after:

```py
async def get_messages_at_date(chat, date):
    result = []
    async for msg in client.iter_messages(chat, offset_date=date):
        if msg.date < date:
            return result
        result.append(msg)
```

Comment: simply `offset_date` doesn't work on `telethon`. I had to compare the `message.date` with the target date to achieve the same goal.

Comment: If you are using `iter_messages` as showcased and `offset_date` is returning messages equal to or after that date, either the implementation is bug (in which case a bug report would be appreciated) or the Telegram server is not honoring the request.

Comment: Tomorrow is not used

Comment: I've removed the `tomorrow` variable to avoid confusion. It was supposed to be what the `date` parameter is, probably.

Comment: @esimonov solution is more elegant

Answer (score 4):

The point made by @Lonami is valid - `offset_date` is used to get messages *prior* to that date. However, the [docs](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.iter_messages) describe another argument called `reverse` that you can supply to `iter_messages` :

> reverse (bool, optional):
> If set to True, the messages will be returned in reverse order (from oldest to newest, instead of the default newest to oldest). **This also means that the meaning of** offset_id and **offset_date** parameters **is reversed**, although they will still be exclusive.

So, if you use it like this:

```php
for message in client.iter_messages(chat, reverse = True, offset_date = date_of_post):
   print(message.sender_id, ':', message.text)
```

it should work as you expected.